# error "Please port gnulib freadahead.c to your platform when compiling kodi

Tags: android, xbmc, kodi

```
freadahead.c: In function 'freadahead':
freadahead.c:91:3: error: #error "Please port gnulib freadahead.c to your platform! Look at the definition of fflush, fread, ungetc on your system, then report this to bug-gnulib."
  #error "Please port gnulib freadahead.c to your platform! Look at the definition of fflush, fread, ungetc on your system, then report this to bug-gnulib."
   ^~~~~
make[6]: *** [Makefile:1837: freadahead.o] Error 1
```

I am getting the error when executing make command

Answer (score 0):

I have installed M4 package and problem gone

Comment: What is M4 package, how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably two issues:

#### 1. M4 package is missing: to fix please install m4

```
sudo apt install m4
```

#### 2. You are compiling outside your system directory:

> In my case I was compiling in a separate mounted location. so I had to move to Desktop or somewhere in the system (under /)

```
mv your_project $HOME/Desktop/
cd $HOME/Desktop/your_project && make
```